# Traveling to Guatemala

Tags: air-travel

Can I travel by air to Guatemala on a one-way ticket? I am asking because forty years ago I was told I could not enter Mexico on a one-way ticket.

Thank you.

Comment: Guatemala is not in Mexico.

Comment: @Itai I think Thomas' point is that at least some countries have issues with this, and perhaps so too does Guatemala.

Comment: Why are you trying to get to Guatemala?

Answer (score 1):

**Guatemalan immigration** officials won't bother you, But your airline at the airport might.

[More detail on lonelyplanet.com](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=1892907)

Answer (score -1):

The flight is *not* the problem, you can fly anywhere on a one-way ticket. The problem - if there is one - is *to be admitted into the target country*.

Depending on your citizenship and visa status, you can enter the target country and stay, or you get a limited visa at the border, or you need to apply for a visa upfront, you might have to prove you have a return ticket, or you can't visit at all.

Unless you add your citizenship and status, nothing more can be deduced.

Check the TIMATIC database with your citizenship and the country you want to go to, and you'll know what you need. The airline will do that too when you board your flight, and they will just not let you board if you don't have what TIMATIC says you need.